# Rails gem for historical breadcrumb effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Folks, this question is probably an easy one, but is there any Rails gem that supports historical breadcrumb trail?

So the requirement would be if I search, then click one product, and then follow to a related product, the breadcrumb would display:

Home > Search: product-name > product 1 > product 2

I checked out crummy, breadcrumb_on_rails and gretel, but I couldn't see any of them suiting this requirements, they seemed to be more hierarchical breadcrumb rather than dynamic.

If there isn't a gem available, has anyone implemented this and could provide a pointer on how to achieve it with custom code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one called `breadcrumbs` :) https://github.com/fnando/breadcrumbs it's kinda old, don't know if it's still supported, but i recall it allowed you to store anything in sort of a history

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, but unfortunately it doesn't support rails 4. I tried to load it with bundler but there wasn't a compatible version....

Comment: Oh well. :) anyways, personally me I'd just build a class for that and store the list in a session. Should be pretty straight forward

Comment: Thanks Nikolay, I found a page that describes how to do it the other day. So I'll just write my own classes, it should be easy enough..